# What do you call the sums of money a university department gets each year for different purposes?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

**Update!**
I just found the word *appropriation*, which seems to capture exactly what I'm after. However, I'm confused that no-one suggested this word when I first asked the question, so perhaps I've completely misunderstood the use of this word?

Each year each department at a university is allocated a sum of money for educating students, a sum of money for research, a sum of money for professional development and so on, right? But what do you call such sums of money? Do you call them *allocations*? Or *grants*? Or... what? And also, what do you call the specific sum allocated for educating students – *education allocation*?? For instance, if I want to say in a more concise way that we need a larger sum of money to fund education, do I say that *we need a larger education allocation*? (I'm pretty sure I can't say this – so what ***can*** I say?)

And just to be clear: I'm not talking about external funding here, but about the money that the university dishes out each year to its various departments.

Comment: Each department has a [**budget**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/budget).

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes, exactly, and in this budget different sums of money, meant for different purposes, are specified right? So what do you call these sums of money?

Comment: These are also bugdets. For example at my uni, the Students' Union was allocated its budget from the uni's central fund, and it decided how its own budget would be subdivided into the various activities and clubs, which in turn...

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh... so can I say "we need a larger education budget" then?

Comment: ...from the edit, each department, club etc applies for a certain budget for the following year, based on the way it used the previous year's budget. It's the same with government departments too, and the money/requests are funnelled downwards/upwards in the hierarchy.

Comment: And so the system has a built-in **overspend & waste** feature. If a department does not spend all its budget, the following year's allocation will be reduced in favour of another department with an apparently bigger need. For the same reason, money can be spent on an apparently useless project, while a needy cause does not get attention.

Comment: @WeatherVane Right, yes – I have a decent idea as to how the system works; I'm just wondering about what expression to use :) So, can I say, for instance, "we need a larger education budget" then?

Comment: Yes, you can say that.

Comment: I agree with the word **budget**.  Sometimes, you'll talk about individual **"line items"** within a budget, especially if there's a large degree of variation expected and one line item might overspend and another one underspend, but the total **budget** is expected to be met without much over/underspend.

Comment: @WeatherVane what do you think about "appropriation" then (see my update)?

Comment: @CanadianYankee What do you think about "appropriation" then (see my update)?

Comment: I think of "appropriation" as being used specifically for money set aside by government legislation - for example, the "National Defense **Appropriation** Act" is in the news in the US right now.  So I might think that a public university might receive an appropriation (perhaps even a targeted appropriation) from the government; but I wouldn't use it for general university funds disbursed to a particular department.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just call it a **budget**.

An appropriation is just the act of taking or allocating. As such it might refer to things other than money - for example the act of cultural appropriation.

Even the term *budget* can be used this way - for example see "energy budget" - but primarily budgets are related to allocations of money.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this-

> **[Allowance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allowance):**
> **Sense 1b-**
> A fixed or available amount.
> **Sense 1c-**
> A share or portion allotted or granted.

So your sentence might look like this:

> *"We need a larger educational **allowance**."*

Comment: Thank you! Would "allowance" be used for the items in an organisation's budget though? I've only heard this word in more "private" contexts, for instance for the sum of money that parents give their kids on a regular basis?

Comment: Yes, you may use both _'allowance'_ or _'budget'_. There's no problem in using both of them. However, I would recommend you to use _'allowance'_ since, you want a word for a specific fund provided (i.e., education only, not collectively for researches, education, development, etc.). It's better to use _'budget'_ when you want to collectively mention these.

Comment: What about appropriation then (see my update)?

Comment: Hey @Hannah , I checked that out and found out that It's a meaning like the one you're asking for. Unfortunately, I hadn't heard such a meaning for this word before. But I wouldn't recommend you to use that word because I saw that it's normally used for money set aside by some companies or a government. Moreover it might confuse the reader due to [these](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appropriate#h2)  meanings(sense 1 and 3).

Comment: If you use the term _"educational appropriation"_ it might mean some funds that are given to support some universities or other educational institutions by the government. I did search for _appropriation in universities_ but all I found was these kind of appropriations not something like a **budget/allowance by a University**